# Shortcut syntax to Class constructor from TypeScript interface

Tags: typescript

If I have a TypeScript interface like below:

```js
interface myInterface {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: number;
    prop4: boolean;
    ..
    ..
    ..
    prop30: string
}
```

I want to create a Class that implements `myInterface` and I only know the verbose way to do so like below:

```js
class MyClass implements myInterface {
    prop1;
    prop2;
    prop3;
    prop4;
    ..
    ..
    prop30;

    constructor(data: myInterface) {
        this.prop1 = data.prop1;
        this.prop2 = data.prop2;
        this.prop3 = data.prop3;
        this.prop4 = data.prop4;
        ..
        ..
        this.prop30 = data.prop30;
    }
}
```

Is there any way I can make this syntax shorter or any better way to implement such Class from interface?

Comment: Is this just a DTO? If so, do you really *need* a class for it?

Comment: Precisely what @VLAZ said - `var x: myInterface = { prop1: "hello", prop2: "world", prop3: 77, ...}` is a valid instance of the interface.  You don't _need_ a class here (just in case you weren't aware).

Comment: I agree you @VLAZ that it is a DTO but I also want some methods to change certain property values based on other property changes (e.g prop1 value changes when props2 and prop3 changes). Hope it makes sense. This is very case specific ask.

Comment: Then it's *not* a DTO if it has *any* logic, not just properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) to copy all the members of the `data` parameter to `this` at once, but TypeScript still requires you to [declare the fields](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#fields) individually:

```
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
    prop1!: string;
    prop2!: string;
    prop3!: number;
    prop4!: boolean;
    /* ..
    ..
    ..*/
    prop30!: string;
    constructor(data: MyInterface) {
        Object.assign(this, data);
    }
}
```

so this is better, but not great.

(Also note that the compiler cannot verify that the properties are assigned, so you need to use the [definite assignment assertion operator (`!`)](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions) in your field declarations to suppress warnings.)

---

You can save yourself this trouble if you are okay defining a *class factory function* and using it to produce a superclass.  Here's the function:

```
function AssignCtor<T extends object>() {
    return class {
        constructor(t: T) {
            Object.assign(this, t)
        }
    } as { new(t: T): T }
}
```

The return value of `AssignCtor<T>` is [asserted](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) a type with a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) that accepts a value of type `T` and produces a class instance also of type `T`.  This is what you want to do with `MyInterface`, so let's try it:

```
class MyClass extends AssignCtor<MyInterface>() implements MyInterface {

}
```

That's it.  Let's make sure that `MyClass` behaves the way you expect:

```
function tryItOut(data: MyInterface) {
    const myClass = new MyClass(data);
    myClass.prop1.toUpperCase(); // okay    
}
```

Looks good.  The value `myClass` is seen to have the properties of `MyInterface`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQQM6pgczAYSnAJwB4AVRAUwA8pywATVROAIwCtzoA+ACgEpEA3gChEoxAXJQQBJBAA2AQ3SCRYtRASooBENELcoALkQl+wtRbEB5NhygA6JRmwGAFjFQAaRFF6rLAL7+iAGISoKIYOQA7gbGpvEhQkFCMGA0BMAKEOSIALIAngCS6eSZ2bnmYgAOBHDVAIzGWgRpmADcwbX1AEzN2m2dat3VAMzGYCAAtsxlQzV11QAsxsxwcHLkCmDzogD0AFT29sHHp-YHe12LowAM-a1gmMlCQmAKU+So1RWIAEKSDJ-EBQABycCgAHEJAooCp1IplIUcIjGDAptVNp90oxCiUMlkcvDLIgRg0AIQPQbBYaLHqUxAtakk0k3BmTGZzGkLepLBlrDZbHbc-YHRBnFkSknHS4i1n1O4MplPXYWDRgFq6fAEbh0WEKYx40rlHJmOVqGzsaCOdBYMBuDzePVQBS8VVqIIel5CeROfIFFF+qg0eiMNDOXDaohGgkVHj8dGY8jYqC44rGwmVV4pUCQWAIHwEYpQKwg3X6w3p2Om4midVaRBTAOoxAAXkiMX9gfQ5ZdbuCTe7qHsZPs+AAqtVqmUcEpyHx2og9nsmABrBQFNTe15AA)

Comment: Thanks @jcalz 
I think class factory function would work for me. I will accept this as an answer once I implement it.

Comment: @jcalz, this is great! One thing I noticed is that the constructor allows unimplemented parameters to make it to the class instance. Any tips for protecting against this?

Comment: @DannyBeyrer if you can provide a [mre] of what you're talking about (like with a tsplay.dev link) then maybe?  Note that comments on previously answered questions are not great places to get followup questions answered; if it turns out to be anything more than a one-liner, then you might want to make your own question post about it.

Comment: Thanks @jcalz. I posted my own question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/70703950/4747264