# Shortcut syntax for typescript constructor using an object allows unimplemented parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript class with a lot of parameters and, if it's possible, I'd like to write a constructor without worrying about the following:

1. Typing `this.a = a, this.b = b, this.c = c...`
2. Passing a list of parameters to the constructor
3. Worrying about stray, unimplemented parameters from being assigned to instances of the class

The following snippet shows code from [the top answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69293235/4747264) which I've slightly modified to make my point. It dynamically assigns a constructor to a superclass, provided an implemented interface.

This is a great solution and provides a reproducible, convenient way to associate a typescript interface with a class constructor. However, as you can see below and in the [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAQQM6pgczAYSnAJwB4AVRAUwA8pywATVROAIwCtzoA%20ACgEpEA3gChEoxAXJQQBJBAA2AQ3SCRYtRASooBENELcoALkQl%20wtRbEB5NhygA6JRmwGAFjFQAaRFF6rLAL7%20iAGISoKIYOQA7gbGpvEhQkFCMGA0BMAKEOSIALIAngCS6eSZ2bnmYgAOBHDVAIzGWgRpmADcwbX1AEzN2m2dat3VAMzGYCAAtsxlQzV11QAsxsxwcHLkCmCdKfJO%20QU4ispUNPSMaM64%20MSFJRlZOTz8MFPVm1O0UIz3peU5FTJIRCUCQWAIHwEYpQKwgKDcOgKKAKYx-R4VMzBDRgLSIKZHE6MAC8kRih2OTkRyIUvHmohxqA25HscjgmG4AHICZT0MZOd4eUS-GohU57CMGvZ8ABVarVMo4JTkPjtRAAenVTAA1goCmpgUJGVBEEiUYhSVVRJL%20QKuos%20ohOXbhotxogAAyee31FZQkDkb2u%20oAVltwO0MLhCLNtJBQA), `prop5` is not in `MyInterface`, yet it is able to be assigned to an instance of `MyClass` via the constructor provided by `AssignCor`.

I'm fairly new to typescript and I'm wondering how we might be able to modify AssignCor to filter out properties that do not exist in the provided interface.

```
function AssignCtor<T extends object>() {
    return class {
        constructor(t: T) {
            Object.assign(this, t)
        }
    } as { new(t: T): T }
}

interface MyInterface {
    prop1: string;
    prop2: string;
    prop3: number;
    prop4: boolean;
}

class MyClass extends AssignCtor<MyInterface>() implements MyInterface {

}

function tryItOut(data: MyInterface) {
    const myClass = new MyClass(data);
    console.log('myClass: ', myClass)
    myClass.prop1.toUpperCase(); // okay    
}

const data = {
    prop1: '',
    prop2: '',
    prop3: 0,
    prop4: true,
    prop5: ''
}

tryItOut(data)
// [LOG]: "myClass: ",  MyClass: {
// "prop1": "",
// "prop2": "",
// "prop3": 0,
// "prop4": true,
// "prop5": ""
// }
```

Comment: You can't ask the interface what its keys are runtime because the type doesn't exist at runtime. There's simply no completely type safe way to deconstruct an object argument into instance variables without doing them one at a time that I've seen. The reason you have to that `as { new(t:T): T }` is because that operation is not actually type safe in the exact way that you've discovered.

Comment: @AlexWayne Hmm, it is type safe; you need an assertion because there’s no way to use the `class` syntax to denote keys that aren’t static (except for an index signature which we also don’t want).  You also can’t convince the compiler that `Object.assign(this, …` will initialize properties.  The problem here is excess properties, which isn’t usually a type safety issue; the OP just doesn’t like it.  (Only type safety issue is if the extra properties clobber anything).  But your general point is right; at the very least you’d need a list of keys at runtime, which will look redundant.

Comment: @jcalz I see your point, but that silent clobbering is exactly why this may matter. With a huge object of configuration, this edge case may be worth considering. https://tsplay.dev/W4yLBw, for example, seems pretty unsound.

Comment: It is unsound but this kind of unsoundness runs through TypeScript all over the place.  Look at [this](https://tsplay.dev/NaYG6N); it's essentially the same issue, but I don't know that we would make a big deal about it.

Comment: @DannyBeyrer so you can't have both 2 and 3.  (By the way I don't think "unimplemented properties" is the right term; from context, you seem to mean what are normally called "excess properties".)  Would you like an answer that says "this is impossible as asked"?  Or is there something more targeted you want to see?

Comment: @jcalz, thanks for the correction. Yeah, I was looking to find out if it was possible or not, so that would be a helpful answer.