# TypeScript Pattern best practices for understanding constructors and class implementation of interfaces with optional properties

Tags: typescript

I have been reading the official [TypeScript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html) and Mozilla and I am trying to understand how to cleanly use interfaces and classes for TypeScript.

Suppose I have this simple example:

```js
interface MyInterface {
  required: string;
  optional?: string;
  another?: number;
}

class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  required;
  optional?;
  another?;

  constructor(instance:MyClass) {
    this.required = instance.required
    this.optional = instance?.optional
    this.another = instance?.another

  }
}
```

My question is why is the following not acceptable? Is there a cleaner pattern to use

```js
// Why can't I do this?
class MyClass implements MyInterface {
  required: string;
  optional?: string;
  another?: number;

  constructor(instance:MyClass) {
    Object.assign(this, instance)
  }
}
```

Comment: I see two questions here; which one is your primary question?  If it's "why is the following not acceptable", it's because the compiler doesn't know that `Object.assign(x, y)` mutates the state of `x`.  If you want to use this pattern you'll have to tell the compiler that, despite its analysis, the required fields really have been assigned, using the *definite assignment operator (`!`)* as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/N9jr7m).  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I am more looking at how to best just pass a single argument to the constructor which is of type `MyInterface` and only have to write all of the props (optional included) in `MyClass` once

Comment: Ah okay then this is essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291358/shortcut-syntax-to-class-constructor-from-typescript-interface) where my answer there translated here would be as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAJbRW).