# Is there a simple pattern in Typescript to write a wrapper Class vor some type without explicily copying every attribute?

Tags: typescript, design-patterns

I often receive raw JSON data from the outer world. (e.g. via http requests)
Often this data represents entities I want to do operations on.
For this purpose I want to write a wrapper class for some given entity, **but without explicitly copying each attribute to the class**!
Is there a way to do this in a type save manner?

Here is my usecase

```js
// This is a wrapper class
new class User {
 // some unknown implementation
}

interface UserDto {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly friends: string[];
}

const user = new User(userDto);
console.log(user.id);
console.log(user.friendsConut()); // this an extension to UserDto
```

And here is the implementation for the User class I want to avoid, for the sake of dry code:

```js
class User {
    readonly id: string;
    readonly friends: string[];
    constructor(dto: UserDto){
         this.id = dto.id;
         this.friends: dto.friends;
    }

    frindsCount(){
        return this.friends.length
    }
```

Comment: You can use the `AssignCtor` approach as shown in the answer to the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291358/shortcut-syntax-to-class-constructor-from-typescript-interface); see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/NDdg1N) for how that might work for your example.