# Typescript: Is there a better way to define classes that construct themselves out of an object they share an interface with?

Tags: typescript

I'm in the process of learning Typescript. I wanted to make a class that constructed itself using a object implementing the same interface as the class. What I came up with was something like this:

```js
interface iItem {
    id: string,
    title: string,
    cost: number,
    quantity?: number,
    target?: string
    sale?: number
}

class Item implements iItem{
    id!: string
    quantity!: 1 // A default value
    title!: string
    cost!: number
    target?: string
    sale?: number
    constructor(item: iItem) {
        Object.assign(this, item);
    }
}
```

The general idea being that I can do something like:

```js
let pants = new Item({id: "pants", title: "pants", cost: 2.99})
```

This pattern seems work well enough, but I'd like to know if there's a better way to do this. Is there something better I can use in the constructor than `Object.assign`? Is there any way to avoid using the non-null assertion operators (eg, `quantity!: 1`)?

Comment: You can assign individual property but that would be un-necessary because if there are so many property then that would be hard to maintain. Better to go with `Object.assign`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  What's going on with `quantity` being `1` in the class but `number` in the interface?  Are you intentionally showing how `Object.assign` is not safe this way (since the chance is good that someone will pass in a non-`1` value for `quantity` to the constructor)?  Or is this an unrelated issue that we should remove so as not to be a distraction?  Either way, please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: (see prev comment)  Once you do that, I think this is probably essentially a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69291358/2887218) and my general approach is to use a class factory function as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/NryoVw).  Let me know if I'm missing something about the question.

Comment: It's not a default value, that's the *type*.  It can *only* be `1`.