# Is there a way to assign lots of properties in class in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

```
interface AType {
  name: string;
  age: number;
  // Other properties...
}

class A {
  name:string;
  age:number;
  constructor(obj: AType) {
    for(let i in obj) {
      this[i]=obj[i];
    }
  }
}
```

This will have several issues:

1. Property 'name' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
2. Property 'age' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
3. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'A'.
   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'A'.
4. Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'AType'.
   No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'AType'.

I know we can apply each value to variables in class in constructor. But if there are too many variables, the constructor will be very big. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: I usually have a class factory function `AssignCtor` which behaves this way; in your example it could look like [this playground example](https://tsplay.dev/wQqqGw). See the linked question/answer for more information.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks, and this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69291358/shortcut-syntax-to-class-constructor-from-typescript-interface also provides a good answer.