# How to use index signature parameter type with a generic type in a class?

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6

For example, I have a class like this. How do I define types for member variables of this class?

```js
class A<T> {
  constructor(data?: T) {
    if (data) {
      Object.assign(this, data);
    }
  }
}
```

A possible approach would be to use `[key : string]: any;`, but this defines the type too broadly.

I've also tried `[key in keyof T]: T[key];`. But typescript doesn't seem to support this kind of writing directly in the class.

Comment: Mixing classes and arbitrary properties seems like a bad idea generally. What's the intended usecase? If you elaborate folks may be able to provide more meaningful alternative suggestions.

Comment: @loganfsmyth To be honest, I'm going to refactor types for warehouse, here is the code [warehouse](https://github.com/hexojs/warehouse/blob/eb60d637d568612a0c5236f1a427685de3109817/src/document.ts#L14C3-L18C4)

Comment: TS doesn’t directly allow class declarations to have arbitrary generic property keys.  Depending on your use case you could use a class factory function like `AssignCtor` in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69293235/2887218). Does that fully address the question? If so I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?